# Identity error at attemt_myuser.email.UNIQUE constraint failed in django project

Tags: django

```
enter code here
```

#This is my models .py :
'like so'

## while post operation through POSTMAN  im getting  error.

```
:connection error after that again hitting POST button data is getting and access token is creating but it is showing unique constrain failed.

from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)

import datetime

class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

def create_superuser(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
    """
    Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
    birth and password.
    """
    user = self.create_user(
        email,
        password=password,
        date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
    )
    user.is_admin = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):

```
email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name='email address',
    max_length=255,
    unique=True,

)
date_of_birth = models.DateField()
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

objects = MyUserManager()

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']

def __str__(self):
    return self.email

def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    "Does the user have a specific permission?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
    # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
    return True

@property
def is_staff(self):
    "Is the user a member of staff?"
    # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
    return self.is_admin
```

class Order(models.Model):

```
Order_id=models.IntegerField(max_length=20)
Product_Name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
Material_Used=models.CharField(max_length=100)
Texture=models.CharField(max_length=50)
Size=models.CharField(max_length=50)
order_date_time=models.DateField(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 1):

change the code `order_date_time=models.DateField(datetime.datetime.now())` to `order_date_time=models.DateField(timezone.now)`
`default=datetime.datetime.now()` is evaluated at parsing/compile time of the model. It is not changed afterwards. To evaluate now() at the time of adding/updating an object, you have to use:
`default=timezone.now`, which sets now as the callable.

Comment: done sir thanks,but my unique constraint error is still there.

Comment: delete the previous migrations from migrations folder and try

Comment: delete the prveius migrations and db also and try

Comment: did both,again same error. 1:while posting it is showing connection refused,2:again  clicking on post showing unique constraint failed.

Comment: i have only one app

Comment: open the migrations folder,  keep only init.py file inside and delete everthing elso, then delete db redo makemigrations and migrate

Comment: did that too,still getting the same error.connection refused and unique constraint.

Comment: Change to timezone.now and see, import it from django.utils

Comment: def create(self, request):
        email = request.data.get('email')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        date_of_birth = request.data.get('date_of_birth')        
        user = MyUser()
        user.email = email
        user.date_of_birth = date_of_birth
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        print('hello')
        app = Application.objects.create(user=user)
        token = generate_token()
        refresh_token = generate_token()

Comment: change to request.POST.get()

Comment: what was the issue?